# Pathogen - only some of vim plugins work

Tags: vim, javascript, plugins, ruby

So recently I installed Pathogen along with a few plugins like NerdTree, and Solarized and they both work really well.

Today I tried to install Ruby indentation plugin (https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax) and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Then I went on and tried to install Javascript indentation/syntax-highlighting plugin (https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport), and here is the funny thing - the advanced syntax highlighting (not the one that comes along with solarized) actually works, but not the indentation.

I think the Pathogen doesn't load `ftplugin` folder. Here's `:scriptnames` output:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
 10: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
 11: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/matchit.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim
 17: ~/.vim/bundle/MatchTagAlways/plugin/MatchTagAlways.vim
 18: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
 20: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
 21: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
 22: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
 23: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
 28: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
 29: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
 30: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
 31: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
 32: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/event.vim
 33: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/notifier.vim
 34: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
 35: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 36: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
 37: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 38: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 39: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 40: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 41: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 42: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 43: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 44: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 45: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 46: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

And here are the first lines of my `.vimrc` files:

```
     execute pathogen#infect()
     syntax on
     filetype plugin indent on
```

I noticed that all plugins that contain `plugin` folder work, whereas plugins with `ftplugin` folder don't. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

I just found out that if I put plugin folder for ruby in `plugin` folder instead of `bundle` it shows up correctly in `:scriptnames` list.

```
 16: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/autoload/rubycomplete.vim
 17: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/compiler/eruby.vim
 18: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/compiler/rake.vim
 19: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/compiler/rspec.vim
 20: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/compiler/ruby.vim
 21: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/compiler/rubyunit.vim
 22: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
 23: ~/.vim/plugin/vim-ruby/ftplugin/eruby.vim
```

and throws following error:

```
Error: Rubycomplete requires vim compiled with +ruby
Error: falling back to syntax completion
```

but the indentation still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your scriptnames does not include even the usual built-in ftplugin or syntax files, for either ruby or for javascript.

So my guess, is you're not editing a ruby or javascript file. Or, if you are, Vim has not detected the file as ruby or javascript.

You can try manually setting the filetype to ruby or javascript, or try to figure out why your Vim isn't detecting them properly. You may not be using a file extension supported by the automatic filetype detection. You can add new file extensions if you like (:help new-filetype); but anyway, Pathogen loads ftplugin files just fine.

Comment: I think vim detects file-types just fine. I have `ftplugin` folder in `.vim` that has `ruby.vim` and `javascript.vim` with a few lines of code for indentation and they both work just fine. (both file-types get correctly indented)
And how can you tell if Pathogen loads ftplugin files if they don't get displayed in `:scriptnames` like all other plugins?

Comment: I'm saying Pathogen in general works fine. As in, "works for me". So, you've got a problem with your setup somewhere, not a problem in Pathogen.

Comment: But in your case, your scriptnames output contains no ftplugin files at all. Which tells me you did not set a filetype or detect one before grabbing that.

Comment: I just edited my original post. The problem is exactly what you said - ftplugin files don't get loaded at all. I set filetype detection if my `.vimrc` file. If I open some `.rb` file and write `:set ft?` command in vim, the output is as expected - `filetype=ruby`